# Prove that $T = cU$, where c is a scalar and $U$ is unitary.

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, unitary-matrices

In $\mathbb{C}^n$, with inner product $\langle z,w \rangle = \sum_{j} z_j\overline{w}_j$. Let $T$ a linear operator such that  $\langle T(z), T(w) \rangle = 0$, if
$\langle z,w \rangle = 0$. Prove that $T = cU$, where c is a scalar and $U$ is unitary. I do not know where to start. I guess I need the matrix representation of $T$ but I do not know. In some exercisa like this I prove that the matrix representation was a diagonal matrix with different $c$ and then I proved that every $c$ was the same... But in this exercise I do not see how to start.

Any hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know polar decomposition (for matrices, not complex numbers)?

Comment: No, Im going to investigate that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\ z,w\in\mathbb{C}^n\ $ with $\ \langle z,w\rangle\ne0\ $, and let
$$
v=z-\|w\|^{-2}\langle z,w\rangle w\ .
$$
Then $\ \langle v,w\rangle=0\ $, and therefore
\begin{align}
0&=\langle Tv,Tw\rangle\\
&=\langle Tz-\|w\|^{-2}\langle w,z\rangle Tw, Tw\rangle\\
&=\langle Tz,Tw\rangle-\|w\|^{-2}\langle w,z\rangle\langle Tw, Tw\rangle\ .
\end{align}
Since $\ \langle z,w\rangle\ne0\ $, this gives
$$
\frac{\|Tw\|^2}{\|w\|^2}=\frac{\langle Tz,Tw\rangle}{\langle z,w\rangle}\ ,
$$
and since the expression left side of this equation is real, so is the one on the right side, and so we have
\begin{align}
\frac{\|Tw\|^2}{\|w\|^2}&=\frac{\langle Tz,Tw\rangle}{\langle z,w\rangle}\\
&=\frac{\langle Tw,Tz\rangle}{\langle w,z\rangle}\\
&=\frac{\|Tz\|^2}{\|z\|^2}\ ,
\end{align}
where last identity follows by reversing the roles of $\ z\ $ and $\ w\ $ in the preceding argument, since $\ \langle w,z\rangle=\overline{\langle z,w\rangle}\ne0\ $.

Now suppose that $\ z,w\in\mathbb{C}^n\ $, with $\  z\ne0\ne w\ $, but $\ \langle z,w\rangle=0\ $. Let $\ u=z+w\ $. Then $\ \langle z,u\rangle=\|z\|^2\ne0\ $ and $\ \langle w,u\rangle=\|w\|^2\ne0\ $.  The above argument now gives us
\begin{align}
\frac{\|Tu\|^2}{\|u\|^2}&=\frac{\|Tz\|^2}{\|z\|^2}\\
&=\frac{\|Tw\|^2}{\|w\|^2}\ .
\end{align}
It follows that $\ \frac{\|Tz\|^2}{\|z\|^2}=\frac{\|Tw\|^2}{\|w\|^2}\ $ for all non-zero $\ z,w\in\mathbb{C}^n\ $. That is, there's a scalar constant $\ c\ $ such that $\ \frac{\|Tz\|^2}{\|z\|^2}=c^2\ $ for all non-zero $\ z\in\mathbb{C}^n\ $.  If $\ c=0\ $ then so is the operator $\ T\ $, and we have $\ T=cU\ $ for *any* unitary operator. Otherwise, we have
$$
\|c^{-1}Tz\|= \|z\|
$$
for all $\ z\in\mathbb{C}^n\ $, which is a sufficient condition for the operator $\ c^{-1}T\ $ to be unitary.